# DateField component, the text field and the button in # lines

Tags: tapestry, datefield

I have started a new project using Tapestry5.4.0 (tapestry5-jquery 4.1.0), i am trying to integrate a datefield component into my tml page, but iam getting a divided component, See pic [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu3s1.png)

Any ideas to solve this issue ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added this piece of code in my css file:

```
  .form-control.hasDatepicker {
          width: 80% !important;
    }
.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    height:34px;
}
```

now it works!